# tasker - opening a whatsapp group based on incoming message from that group

Tags: whatsapp, tasker

I'm familier with tasker's "shortcut" function, that allows pre-selecting a group on whatsapp and having that group open on command.

I'm trying to open a whatsapp group upon certain message that came from that group (that contain's a certain keyword, for example), without knowing in advance which whatsapp group it is.

The case is this:
I have 150 employees, each one of them is a member of 100-200 whatsapp groups. Most messages from all those groups are irrelevant to them. When certain keyword appears on a message, it is relevant, so I want to offer a quick open of that whatsapp group. Those whatsapp groups are changing, expending, change their name, new ones are created - the tasker function should be able to open a whatsapp group without me knowing the group before hand, based on the incoming message from that group.

Tried getting notification variables - non of them seem to contain that whatsapp group id. Unfortunately I'm not a "real" programmer so I'll have to stick with Tasker... Also it should include autoinput actions which is easier to do in Tasker, But if it requires some in-tasker scripting I might be able to handle it ;-)